# Can someone explain the meaning of malloc(20 * c | -(20 * (unsigned __int64)(unsigned int)c >> 32 != 0))

Tags: c++, c, assembly

In decompiled code generated by IDA I see expressions like:

```
malloc(20 * c | -(20 * (unsigned __int64)(unsigned int)c >> 32 != 0))
malloc(6  * n | -(3  * (unsigned __int64)(unsigned int)(2 * n) >> 32 != 0))
```

Can someone explain the purpose of these calculations?

c and n are int (signed integer) values.

**Update.**

Original C++ code was compiled with MSVC for 32-bit platform.

Here's assembly code for second line of decompiled C-code above (malloc(6 * ..)):

```
mov     ecx, [ebp+pThis]
mov     [ecx+4], eax
mov     eax, [ebp+pThis]
mov     eax, [eax]
shl     eax, 1
xor     ecx, ecx
mov     edx, 3
mul     edx
seto    cl
neg     ecx
or      ecx, eax
mov     esi, esp
push    ecx             ; Size
call    dword ptr ds:__imp__malloc
```

Comment: Whoever wrote this code should be executed. This code takes the abuse of operator precedence to a new level.

Comment: Isn't this is just pseudo `C` code optimized by the compiler?

Comment: I suspect this is some kind of misunderstanding of the compiler-generated code. Like a sign-extend of a 32 -> 64-bit number in an optimised form. Most likely (c >> 32) is zero.

Comment: Can you please reference where did you find such code?

Comment: Decompiled code is not usually human readable. The decompiler is replicating all the bizarre edge quirks of the generated assembly in a high-level language, so it's going to look super weird. (Likely, here it's replicating odd overflow characteristics that the assembly happens to have.)

Comment: It would help if you tell us what `sizeof(int)` is on the machine in question, and what the type of `c` and `n` are

Comment: @user3528438 apparently the code was generated by a decompiler -- so the decompiler must have been executed already !

Comment: It might also be illuminating to see the original assembly, it's probably shorter than this C code

Comment: This is so amazingly obfuscated yet valid that I'm adding it to my secure coding course!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing that original source code used the C++ `new` operator to allocate an array and was compiled with Visual C++. As user3528438's answer indicates this code is meant to prevent overflows. Specifically it's a 32-bit unsigned saturating multiply. If the result of the multiplication would be greater than 4,294,967,295, the maximum value of a 32-bit unsigned number, the result is clamped or "saturated" to that maximum.

Since Visual Studio 2005, Microsoft's C++ compiler has [generated code to protect against overflows](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michael_howard/archive/2005/12/06/500629.aspx). For example, I can generate assembly code that could be decompiled into your examples by compiling the following with Visual C++:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void *
operator new[](size_t n) {
        return malloc(n);
}

struct S {
        char a[20];
};

struct T {
        char a[6];
};

void
foo(int n, S **s, T **t) {
        *s = new S[n];
        *t = new T[n * 2];
}
```

Which, with Visual Studio 2015's compiler generates the following assembly code:

```
    mov esi, DWORD PTR _n$[esp]
    xor ecx, ecx
    mov eax, esi
    mov edx, 20                 ; 00000014H
    mul edx
    seto    cl
    neg ecx
    or  ecx, eax
    push    ecx
    call    _malloc
    mov ecx, DWORD PTR _s$[esp+4]
; Line 19
    mov edx, 6
    mov DWORD PTR [ecx], eax
    xor ecx, ecx
    lea eax, DWORD PTR [esi+esi]
    mul edx
    seto    cl
    neg ecx
    or  ecx, eax
    push    ecx
    call    _malloc
```

Most of the decompiled expression is actually meant to handle just one assembly statement. The assembly instruction `seto cl` sets CL to 1 if the previous MUL instruction overflows, otherwise it sets CL to 0. Similarly the expression `20 * (unsigned __int64)(unsigned int)c >> 32 != 0` evaluates to 1 if the result of `20 * c` overflows, and evaluates to 0 otherwise.

If this overflow protection wasn't there and the result of `20 * c` did actually overflow then the call to `malloc` would probably succeed, but allocate much less memory than the program intended.  The program would then likely write past the end of the memory actually allocated and trash other bits of memory. This would amount to a buffer overrun, one that could be potentially exploited by hackers.

Comment: You are right, this code was compiled by MSVC and its disassembly listing is almost identical to yours. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Since this code is decompiled from ASM, so we can only guess what it actually does.

Let's first format it so figure the precedence:

```
malloc(20 * c | -(20 * (unsigned __int64)(unsigned int)c >> 32 != 0))
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                       //this is first evaluated, promoting c to 
                       //64 bit unsigned int without doing sign
                       //extension, regardless the type of c

malloc(20 * c | -(20 * (uint64_t)c >> 32 != 0))
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                  //then, multiply by 20, with uint64 result

malloc(20 * c | -(20 * (uint64_t)c >> 32 != 0))
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                  //if 20c is greater than 2^32-1, then result is true,
                  //use -1 to generate a mask of 0xffffffff,
                  //bitwise operator | then masks 20c to 0xffffffff 
                  //(2^32-1, the maximum of size_t, input type to malloc)
                  //regardless what 20c actually is

                  //if 20c is smaller than 2^32-1, then result is false,
                  //the mask is 0, bitwise operator | keeps the final    
                  //input to malloc as 20c untouched
```

**What are 20 and 6?**

Those probably come from the common usage of 
`malloc(sizeof(Something)*count)`. Those two calls to `malloc` are probably made with `sizeof(Something)` and `sizeof(SomethingElse)` evaluated to `20` and `6` at compile time.

**So what this code actually does:**

My guess, it's trying to prevent `sizeof(Something)*count` from overflowing and cause the `malloc` to succeed and cause buffer overflow when the memory is used.

By evaluating the product in 64 bit unsigned `int` and test against `2^32-1`, when size is greater than `2^32-1`, the input to `malloc` is set to a very large value that makes it guaranteed to fail (No 32 bit system can allocate 2^32-1 bytes of memory).

Comment: Ugh.  Hopefully that's from disassembling an optimized `if (...)` statement and someone didn't code that directly.

Comment: "regardless the type of c" - well, if `c` were a wider type than `unsigned int` then some information is lost

Answer (score 1):

<strike>it's rounding up to the nearest block size.</strike>

forgive me. What it's doing is calculating a multiple of c while simultaneously checking for a negative value (overflow):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>


size_t foo(char c)
{
    return 20 * c | -(20 * (std::uint64_t)(unsigned int)c >> 32 != 0);
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    for (char i = -4 ; i < 4 ; ++i)
    {
        cout << "input is: " << int(i) << ", result is " << foo(i) << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

results:

```
input is: -4, result is 18446744073709551615
input is: -3, result is 18446744073709551615
input is: -2, result is 18446744073709551615
input is: -1, result is 18446744073709551615
input is: 0, result is 0
input is: 1, result is 20
input is: 2, result is 40
input is: 3, result is 60
```

> To me the number 18446744073709551615 doesn't mean much, at a glance. Only after seeing it expressed in hex I went "ah". – Jongware

adding << hex:

```
input is: -1, result is ffffffffffffffff
```

Comment: @ScottHunter With code like this, it's best not to think too much about it. If it works, fine. If it doesn't work, throw it all away and write something yourself. Don't try to understand it.

Comment: @MrLister: The answer came from *somewhere*; its a pretty thin one w/o some elaboration.

Comment: This code is generated by decompiler: this is C code corresponding to ASM code generated by x86 compiler. I am trying to understand why this code has been generated like this - would any malloc(N) expression in original program imply these additional alignments when compiled?

Comment: @leo it's a way of ensuring that any negative value will cause a failed allocation. The result of the expression for any negative value is 0xffffffffffffffff.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that compiler would always generate code like this when malloc is called with signed int value? I can post original ASM code from disassembler if it helps, it's just less readable.

Comment: @leo I can't say whether all compilers will do this. could it be that what you're actually seeing is inlined `calloc`? It's a good way of ensuring that asking for more blocks than can possibly fit in the memory model is refused.

Comment: To me the number `18446744073709551615` doesn't mean much, at a glance. Only after seeing it expressed in hex I went "ah".

Comment: @Jongware thanks for pointing that out - answer updated accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone explain the purpose of these calculations?

It is important to understand that compiling changes the semantic meaning of code. Much unspecified behavior of the original code becomes specified by the compilation process.

IDA has no idea whether things the generated assembly code just happens to do are important or not. To be safe, it tries to perfectly replicate the behavior of the assembly code, even in cases that cannot possibly happen given the way the code is used.

Here, IDA is probably replicating the overflow characteristics that the conversion of types just happens to have on this platform. It can't just replicate the original C code because the original C code likely had unspecified behavior for some values of `c` or `n`, likely negative ones.

For example, say I write this C code: `int f(unsigned j) { return j; }`. My compiler will likely turn that into very simple assembly code giving whatever behavior for negative values of `j` that my platform just happens to give.

But if you decompile the generated assembly, you *cannot* decompile it to `int f(unsigned j) { return j; }` because that will not behave the same as the my assembly code did on platforms with different overflow behavior. That could compile to code (on other platforms) that returns different values than my assembly code does for negative values of `j`.

So it is often literally impossible (in fact, incorrect) to decompile C code into the original code, it will often have these kinds of "portably replicate this platform's behavior" oddities.