# Strange code generated by 64-bit compiler when calling malloc in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c, visual-studio, assembly

The following C code will result in passing `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` to `malloc()` instead of the expected 0, when compiled for x64 by Visual Studio 2013:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int x = -1;
    void *p = malloc(x + 1);
}
```

Opening the disassembly view reveals this strange snippet (Debug configuration, although Release is functionally the same):

```
; int x = -1;
mov         dword ptr [x],0FFFFFFFFh  
; void *p = malloc(x + 1);
mov         eax,dword ptr [x]  
add         eax,1  
mov         eax,eax  
mov         rcx,0FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFh  
cmovb       rax,rcx  
mov         rcx,rax  
call        qword ptr [__imp_malloc (07F79C80B228h)]  
mov         qword ptr [p],rax
```

Casting to size_t won't change anything, but storing the result to a temporary variable and then passing that to malloc() will.

Strangely, this does not happen when calling any other function similarly declared:

```
void * __cdecl foo(size_t y) {
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int x = -1;
    void *p = foo(x + 1);
}
```

In this case, the correct code is generated (note the missing `cmovb` stuff):

```
; int x = -1;
mov         dword ptr [x],0FFFFFFFFh  
; void *p = foo(x + 1);
mov         eax,dword ptr [x]  
inc         eax  
cdqe  
mov         rcx,rax  
call        foo (07F6AB84100Ah)  
mov         qword ptr [p],rax
```

I hesitate to call this a code generation bug. I must assume it's something I'm missing. However, I've never seen this before and it certainly produces incorrect behavior.

Why is this happening?

Comment: `main` should return `int`, not `void`. I've seen some options in clang to make `char` always unsigned. Perhaps the same happens with your `int`, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Well, it is implementation-defined whether `[m/c/re]alloc(0)` returns `NULL` or a valid pointer that cannot be dereferenced. It might be that visual studio passes `SIZE_MAX` to `malloc()` to ensure the allocation fails, returning `NULL` in this case.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj161081.aspx

Comment: ForceBru, you're right about main. Changed wrong return type to int. Changing the type of x to unsigned int makes no difference though (it shouldn't).

Comment: @EOF According to Microsoft [malloc(0)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ewkz86d.aspx) does this in their environment: _If size is 0, malloc allocates a zero-length item in the heap and returns a valid pointer to that item._

Comment: @EOF, that's not the problem. You can add 2 instead of 1 to x for example, result will still be the same.

Comment: What happens when you add `__declspec(guard(overflow))` to `foo()`?

Comment: @HansPassant You're right! Disabling SDL checks removes the extra code.

Comment: @MichaelPetch but didn't `add eax,1` set the carry flag?

Comment: I find it strange that in the `foo` example `eax` is extended to 64-bits to be a `size_t` argument, but that does not happen in the first case (when carry not set).

Comment: @Michael Petch Adding 1 to -1 sets the carry flag.

Comment: @WeatherVane : I thought I saw 1 being added to _RAX_ (not EAX). I quickly skimmed the code. Yes on _EAX_ CF would be 1, so I retract the comment. Had it been RAX it would have not set _CF_.

Comment: @cremno It doesn't seem to be recognized by Visual Studio 2013 ('Error: unknown attribute "guard"'). You're close though, the 'incorrect' code is due to SDL checks!

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34442943/can-someone-explain-the-meaning-of-malloc20-c-20-unsigned-int64uns/34443299#34443299

Comment: @ForceBru: `int` is always `signed int`.

Comment: Yet another reason `malloc(0)` is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

It's a safeguard against integer overflow (as referenced in the comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34442943/can-someone-explain-the-meaning-of-malloc20-c-20-unsigned-int64uns/34443299#34443299)).

If the value passed to `malloc` is the result of an integer overflow (signed or unsigned), rather than letting the program allocate less memory than the compiler thinks it expected, it maxes out the expression and attempts to allocate that.

Comment: Just a side note: since the value 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF exceeds _HEAP_MAXREQ which is 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0, `malloc` will result in an ENOMEM error in `errno`